# Batch Script To Extract Lines Between Specified Words

Tags: batch-file, scripting, extract, lines

I have a log file like below.

> [Tue Aug 19 10:45:28 2014]Local/PLPLAN/PL/giuraja@MSAD/2172/Info(1019025)
>
> Reading Rules From Rule Object For Database [PL]
>
> [Tue Aug 19 10:45:28 2014]Local/PLPLAN/PL/giuraja@MSAD/2172/Info(1013157)
>
> Received Command [Import] from user [giuraja@MSAD] using [AIF0142.rul] with data file [SQL]
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> Clear Active on User [giuraja@MSAD] Instance [1]
>
> .
>
> .

I want to extract the line starting with "[Tue Aug 19 10:" until the line that starts with "Clear Active on User" and output to a file using windows batch script. I tried the below code. It only outputs the last line.

> @echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
>
> set Month_Num=%date:~4,2%
>
> if %Month_Num%==08 set Month_Name=Aug
>
> set Day=%date:~0,3%
>
> set Today_Date=%date:~7,2%
>
> set Search_String=[%Day% %Month_Name% %Today_Date% 10:
>
> for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "%Search_String%"^
>
> @(
>
> more +%%a D:\Hyperion\ERPI_Actuals_Load\Logs\PLPLAN.LOG)>D:\Hyperion\ERPI_Actuals_Load\Logs\PLPLAN_Temp.txt
>
> (for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (D:\Hyperion\ERPI_Actuals_Load\Logs\PLPLAN_Temp.txt) do (
>
> set test=%%a
>
> if "!test:~0,20!" equ "Clear Active on User" goto :eof
>
> echo %%a
>
> ))>D:\Hyperion\ERPI_Actuals_Load\Logs\PLPLAN_Formatted.txt

Regards,
Ragav.

Answer (score 2):

The Batch file below was designed to process as fast as possible a big file; however, it deletes empty lines from result:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "start=[Tue Aug 19 10:"
set "end=Clear Active on User"

for /F %%a in ("%start%") do set startWord=%%a
for /F %%a in ("%end%") do set endWord=%%a

set "startLine="
set "endLine="
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('findstr /I /N /B /C:"%start%" /C:"%end%" logFile.txt') do (
   if not defined startLine if "%%b" equ "%startWord%" set startLine=%%a
   if not defined endLine if "%%b" equ "%endWord%" set "endLine=%%a" & goto continue0
)
:continue0
set /A skipLines=startLine-1, numLines=endLine-startLine+1
set "skip="
if %skipLines% gtr 0 set skip=skip=%skipLines%

(for /F "%skip% delims=" %%a in (logFile.txt) do (
   echo %%a
   set /A numLines-=1
   if !numLines! equ 0 goto continue1
)) > outFile1.txt
:continue1

rem Previous outFile1.txt contain as many extra lines as empty lines removed, so we need to eliminate they

for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /B /C:"%end%" outFile1.txt') do set numLines=%%a
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (outFile1.txt) do (
   echo %%a
   set /A numLines-=1
   if !numLines! equ 0 goto continue2
)) > outFile2.txt
:continue2

del outFile1.txt
TYPE outFile2.txt
```

If you want to preserve empty lines, the process would be *much* slower.

Comment: Thanks. It works. what should I do to keep the empty lines? I can split the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is an inclusive (start and end line are shown) script that should do the job.  You can modify it to exclude the lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set filename=text_file.txt
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:"  %%a in ('findstr /n /b /c:"[Tue Aug " %filename%') do (
    set /a f_line=%%a-1
)

for /f "tokens=1 delims=:"  %%a in ('findstr /n /b /c:"Clear Active on User" %filename%') do (
    set /a l_line=%%a
)
 echo %l_line% -- %f_line%

call :tail_head2 -file=%filename% -begin=%f_line%  -end=%l_line% 


exit /b 0




@echo off
:tail_head2
setlocal


rem ---------------------------
rem ------ arg parsing --------
rem ---------------------------

    if "%~1" equ "" goto :help
        for %%H in (/h -h /help -help) do (
                if /I "%~1" equ "%%H" goto :help
        )
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
            set "prev="
            for %%A in (%*) do (
                    if /I "!prev!" equ "-file" set file=%%~fsA
                    if /I "!prev!" equ "-begin" set begin=%%~A
                    if /I "!prev!" equ "-end" set end=%%A
                    set prev=%%~A
            )
        endlocal & (
                if "%file%" neq "" (set file=%file%)
                if "%begin%" neq "" (set /a begin=%begin%)
                if "%end%" neq "" (set /a end=%end%)
        )

rem -----------------------------
rem --- invalid cases check -----
rem -----------------------------

        if "%file%" EQU "" echo file not defined && exit /b 1
        if not exist "%file%"  echo file not exists && exit /b 2
        if not defined begin if not defined end echo neither BEGIN line nor END line are defined && exit /b 3

rem --------------------------
rem -- function selection ----
rem --------------------------

        if defined begin if %begin%0 LSS 0 for /F %%C in ('find /c /v "" ^<"%file%"')  do set /a lines_count=%%C
        if defined end if %end%0 LSS 0 if not defined lines_count for /F %%C in ('find /c /v "" ^<"%file%"')  do set lines_count=%%C

                rem -- begin only
        if not defined begin if defined end if %end%0 GEQ 0 goto :end_only
        if not defined begin if defined end if %end%0 LSS 0 (
                        set /a end=%lines_count%%end%+1
                        goto :end_only
                )

                rem -- end only
        if not defined end if defined begin if %begin%0 GEQ 0 goto :begin_only
        if not defined end if defined begin if %begin%0 LSS 0 (
                        set /a begin=%lines_count%%begin%+1
                        goto :begin_only
                )
                rem -- begin and end
        if %begin%0 LSS 0 if %end%0 LSS 0 (
                        set /a begin=%lines_count%%begin%+1
                        set /a end=%lines_count%%end%+1
                        goto :begin_end
                )
        if %begin%0 LSS 0 if %end%0 GEQ 0 (
                        set /a begin=%lines_count%%begin%+1
                        goto :begin_end
                )
        if %begin%0 GEQ 0 if %end%0 LSS 0 (
                        set /a end=%lines_count%%end%+1
                        goto :begin_end
                )
        if %begin%0 GEQ 0 if %end%0 GEQ 0 (
                        goto :begin_end
                )      
goto :eof

rem -------------------------
rem ------ functions --------
rem -------------------------

rem -----  single cases -----

:begin_only
        setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /R /N "^" "%file%"') do (
                set "line=%%L"
                for /F "delims=:" %%n in ("%%L") do (
                        if %%n GEQ %begin% (
                                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                                set "text=!line:*:=!"
                                (echo(!text!)
                                endlocal
                        )
                )
        )
        endlocal
endlocal
goto :eof

:end_only
        setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
        for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /R /N "^" "%file%"') do (
                set "line=%%L"
                for /F "delims=:" %%n in ("%%L") do (
                        IF %%n LEQ %end% (
                                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                                set "text=!line:*:=!"
                                (echo(!text!)
                                endlocal
                        ) ELSE goto :break_eo
                )
        )
        :break_eo
        endlocal
endlocal
goto :eof

rem ---  end and begin case  -----

:begin_end
        setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
        if %begin% GTR %end% goto :break_be
        for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /R /N "^" "%file%"') do (
                set "line=%%L"
                for /F "delims=:" %%n in ("%%L") do (
                    IF %%n GEQ %begin% IF %%n LEQ %end% (        
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                        set "text=!line:*:=!"
                       (echo(!text!)
                        endlocal
                    ) ELSE goto :break_be                              
                )
        )
        :break_be
        endlocal
endlocal
goto :eof
rem ------------------
rem --- HELP ---------
rem ------------------
:help
    echo(
        echo %~n0 - dipsplays a lines of a file defined by -BEGIN and -END arguments passed to it
        echo(
        echo( USAGE:
        echo(
        echo %~n0  -file=file_to_process {-begin=begin_line ^| -end=end_line }
        echo or
        echo %~n0  -file file_to_process {-begin begin_line ^| -end end_line }
        echo(
        echo( if some of arguments BEGIN or END has a negative number it will start to count from the end of file
        echo(
        echo( http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php^?id^=1707
        echo(
goto :eof
```

**EDIT** - last 100 lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set filename=text_file.txt
for /F %%C in ('find /c /v "" ^<"%filename%"')  do set /a lines_count=%%C
set /a last_100_lines=lines_count-100

type %filename% | more /e +%last_100_lines%
```

Comment: Thanks. The script ran for about 6 minutes and later I terminated it. The file size can be as high as 400 MB.

Comment: @user1492218 whoa...This script is not the best way to process big files.May be some external tools will help (tail,head ports may be).Did this at least printed the number lines - the `echo` with the `--` in the middle?

Comment: Yes. It printed the number of lines. It would be helpful if I can extract the last 100 lines using batch script.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (tested)

```
@echo off
set "st_line=Tue Aug 19"
set "end_line=Clear Active on User"
for /f "delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /inc:"%st_line%" logfile.txt') do (set st_line_ln=%%i)
for /f "delims=:" %%j in ('findstr /inc:"%end_line%" logfile.txt') do (set end_line_ln=%%j)

findstr /in /c:[a-z] /c:[0-9] /rc:"^$" logfile.txt >logfile_ln.txt

set /a "st_line_ln_temp=%st_line_ln-1"

for /f "skip=%st_line_ln_temp% tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('type logfile_ln.txt') do (
 if %%a leq %end_line_ln% (echo.%%b) 
)

del logfile_ln.txt
```

Sample output -

```
C:\test>type logfile.txt
Tue Aug 19 10:45:28 2014]Local/PLPLAN/PL/giuraja@MSAD/2172/Info(1019025)

Reading Rules From Rule Object For Database [PL]

[Tue Aug 19 10:45:28 2014]Local/PLPLAN/PL/giuraja@MSAD/2172/Info(1013157)

Received Command [Import] from user [giuraja@MSAD] using [AIF0142.rul] with data file [SQL]

test1
test2
test4
test546
Clear Active on User [giuraja@MSAD] Instance [1
test1212
test232
test67
dj

C:\test>draft.bat
[Tue Aug 19 10:45:28 2014]Local/PLPLAN/PL/giuraja@MSAD/2172/Info(1013157)

Received Command [Import] from user [giuraja@MSAD] using [AIF0142.rul] with data file [SQL]

test1
test2
test4
test546
Clear Active on User [giuraja@MSAD] Instance [1
C:\test>
```

Cheers, G

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. The file size is around 400 MB and it gets stuck when i execute. When I tried on the same logfile.txt you used, It just adds line number to each line and output to logfile_ln.txt. I also get this error.  tokens=1* delims=:" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Error you have mentioned usually appears if you have missed any quote symbols `'` or `"`. Can you closely look one more time

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: If you don't want to preserve empty lines
SET "select="
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q25390541.txt) DO (
  ECHO %%a|FINDSTR /b /L /c:"[Tue Aug 19 10:" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET select=y
  IF DEFINED select ECHO(%%a
  ECHO %%a|FINDSTR /b /L /c:"Clear Active on User" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO done1
 )
)>newfile.txt

:done1

:: If you want to preserve empty lines
SET "select="
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" q25390541.txt') DO (
  IF "%%b"=="" (
   IF DEFINED select ECHO(
  ) ELSE (
   ECHO %%b|FINDSTR /b /L /c:"[Tue Aug 19 10:" >NUL
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET select=Y
   IF DEFINED select ECHO(%%b
   ECHO %%b|FINDSTR /b /L /c:"Clear Active on User" >NUL
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO done2
  )
 )
)>newfile2.txt

:done2

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q25390541.txt` containing your data for my testing.
Produces `newfile.txt` and `newfile2.txt` depending on which is preferred.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But there are more instances of the string "Clear Active on User". I want all the lines between the lines starting with "[Tue Aug 19 10" and till the last instance of the string "Clear Active on User".

Comment: You've supplied too little sample data. You say "the line that starts with" which implies there is only one. If you mean "the **last** line that starts with" then say that. It's quite different and very significant. After a month, you've said that you want to preserve empty lines - in a comment on an answer, not by putting it in the original question. We don't know the structure of your file, or the section that you require. You need to be **very** specific about these things.

Comment: Perhaps if you were to extract from the first occurrence of `[Tue...` to the first occurrence of `[Wed...` (or it might be a line starting `[` but not starting `[Tue Aug 19 10`) then that alone may fit your requirement. Without representative data - especially explicit examples of the `end of data that I want to extract` dataline-sequence, we're reduced to a guessing-game.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I wasnt specific because I later understood the format of the file.