# Batch | copy text between two lines in loop

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy all parts from `LOAD` to the subsequent `;` (semi-colon) and this in an loop. I'm new to Batch and I want to know if it is possible to do this with batch, thx.

This is my txt-file:

> ```
> ALTER TABLE DRIVE(ID);      
> SELECT COUNT(*) DRIVE;   
> LOAD INTO ID, VALUES                                         
> CAR , BUS,  LIMO); 
>
> ALTER TABLE TEMP(ID);      
> SELECT COUNT(*) TEMP;   
> LOAD INTO ID, VALUES                                         
> HOT , COLD,  OK);
> ```

I need everything from `LOAD` to `;`

> ```
> LOAD INTO ID, VALUES                                         
> CAR , BUS,  LIMO);
> ```

My idea:

1. Search for first `LOAD` in text -> save line-number1, then search the next `;` in text- save line-number2.
2. Then copy block (everything from line number1 to linenumber2) in target txt-file.
3. Delete all text till line-number2.
4. Start script again (loop) and add every new text block to target-file.
5. End script while end of text reached and no `LOAD` is in text.

```
@echo off

set "dataFile=C:\Users\ebeta\Desktop\work3\data.txt"

rem search the starting line
    set "startLine="
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in (
        'findstr /l /b /n /c:"LOAD" "%dataFile%"'
    ) do if not defined startLine set "startLine=%%a"

rem remove all lines before the starting one    
    if defined startLine for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in (
        'findstr /n "^" "%dataFile%" ^& break ^> "%dataFile%"'
    ) do if %%a geq %startLine% >>"%dataFile%" echo(%%b

rem search the semicolon line
    set "semicolonLine="
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in (
        'findstr /l /b /n /c:";" "%dataFile%"'
    ) do if not defined semicolonLine set "semicolonLine=%%a" 


    sed -n '%startLine%','%semicolonLine%' > target.txt

rem remove all lines before the semicolon one    
    if defined semicolonLine for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in (
        'findstr /n "^" "%dataFile%" ^& break ^> "%dataFile%"'
    ) do if %%a geq %semicolonLine% >>"%dataFile%" echo(%%b

    )
)

goto start
```

- It finds startingLine and  deletes all lines to startingLine.
- I think the search for semicolonLine should work.
- But it does not copy the textblock to target.txt file.
- Problem -> `sed -n '%startLine%','%semicolonLine%' > target.txt`.
- First question: how do I use the line variables to get my textblock defined for transfer to target-file?  Can I use the `sed` command this way ?
- Second question: I don't know how to loop the batch script? I found the command `goto start`. But this seems not to work. And when does the script ends running?

Comment: Yes it's possible! If when you've written it, it exhibits an issue, feel free to update your question, to make it on topic.

Comment: You've posted a list of requirements. Make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. There are existing posts here that solve various parts of what you're trying to do, such as locate specific text in a text file, delete text from a text file, and more. You've listed several tasks. Pick one and work on doing that using the existing questions here. When you've got that working, start working on the next step. Rinse and repeat until you've got it working. If you run into issues along the way, you can explain the problem you're having, include your code in the form of a [mre], and ask.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. I needed the save call that it should be possible, because Isurfed for hours, but not found exactly my problem. That was  intention. Do I have to post my questions to the script in a new post ? thanks

Comment: The 2nd question is obsolete if a `for` loop or similar processes the whole file. `goto start` makes the interpreter search for a line `:start`, which is known as a label. I do not use `sed` so I have avoided it in my answer. Consider a refresh with a [tour].

Comment: [related or even a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390541/batch-script-to-extract-lines-between-specified-words)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "target=C:\Users\ebeta\Desktop\work3\data.txt"
set "found="

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "%target%" ^& break ^> "%target%"') do (
    if defined found (
        >> "%target%" echo %%A
        echo %%A| findstr /r /c:"; *$" >nul && set "found="
    ) else for /f "delims= " %%B in ("%%~A") do (
        if "%%~B" == "LOAD" (
            >> "%target%" echo %%A
            set "found=1"
        )
    )
)
```

This does not trim any spaces from the end of lines as the sample in the question does have trailing spaces. Special characters can be an issue with the `echo` piped to `findstr`. I tried a delayed expansion version and still can be issue.

An alternative:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "target=C:\Users\ebeta\Desktop\work3\data.txt"
set "pattern=(?sm)^LOAD .+?;"

powershell -noprofile -command^
 "$content = get-content -path '%target%' -raw;"^
 "$content = $content -replace '(?m)\s+$','';"^
 "$load = select-string '%pattern%' -input $content -allmatches;"^
 "if ($load.matches.count -eq 0) {exit 1};"^
 "set-content -path '%target%' -value $load.matches -force"

if errorlevel 1 (
    >&2 echo No replacements occurred.
    exit /b 1
)
```

This code uses `powershell` to trim the trailing spaces and get the text of interest. If replacements occur, then `errorlevel` will be `0`, else `1`. Unaware of any issues. The `if errorlevel 1` at the end is just to show how to check if failure happens. The `target` is only written to if replacements do occur, unlike the previous code which erases the file. If you want a blank file if no replacements, remove the 2nd last line of the `powershell` command:

```
"if ($load.matches.count -eq 0) {exit 1};"^
```

is the optional line to remove.